# Filling in a Cell of Matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

In Matlab I am trying to create a cell of size 16 x1 where each entry of this cell is a matrix. I have the following equation

```
  $$W_g = exp^{\frac{j{2\pi m}{N}(n+\frac{g}{G}))}  \,\,\,\,\,\,\, m,n=0,1,.....(N-1)$$
```

for this work assume $N=4$  and the index $g$ is the index that refers to the cell element i.e g=0:1:15

```
W=cell(16,1);

for g=1:16
for m=1:3
    for n=1:3
        W{g,m,n}= exp((2*pi*j*m/4)*      n+(g-1)/16));
end 
end
end
```

How can I make this work? I have two problems with this, you see g starts from 0 and MATLAB doesnt accept index of zero and how to actually define the matrices within the cell.

Thanks

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't handle LaTeX. Also add 1 to `g`? `W{g+1, m, n}`

Comment: thank you. what would be best way to show this equation

Comment: @Henry I tried running your equation through a LaTeX editor. It doesn't render. You can use this website: https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php ... to create an image representation of the equation that you can use to embed into your post.  Correct your equation, render the image then embed it into your post here.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you have this equation:

[image]

And you just want the following code:

```
W=cell(16,1);

n = 1:3;
m = 1:3;
N = 4;
for g=1:16
        W{g}= exp((2*pi*j.*m/4*N).*n+(g-1)/16);
end

%or the 1 line version:

W = cellfun(@(g) exp((2*pi*j.*m/4*N).*n+(g-1)/16),num2cell([1:16]),'UniformOutput',0);
```

With matlab you can use the [Element-wise multiplication](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) symbol `.*`

For example:

```
%A matrix multiplication
A = [2,3]
B = [1,3]';

result = A * B %result = 11

%An element wise multiplication
A = [2,3]
B = [1,3];

result = A .* B %result = [2,9]
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, i is the complex number in matlab (sqrt(-1)) not j, and you are correct, matlab is indexed in 1, so simply start counting g at 1, until 16.

Next, create a zero matrix, and calculate all indices accordingly.  Something like this should work just fine :

```
clc
clear all

W=cell(16,1);

for g=1:16;

    temp = zeros(3,3);
    for m=1:3
        for n=1:3

            temp (m,n) = exp((2*pi*1i*m/4)*      n+g/16);
        end

    end

    W{g} = temp;
end
```

if you are considering doing much larger operations, consider using linspace to create your m and n indices and using matrix operations

Comment: Actually both `i` and `j` are `sqrt(-1)`. Also `g` is part of the equation so you likely don't want to do `g = 1:16`.

Comment: I assumed OP needed g to change on every iteration because of how he posted his for loop initially.  You could of course set another variable G as a constant.  Did not know j was also complex by default in matlab, I learned something new today ;)

Comment: @Henry It's hard to say since you still haven't put the *actual* equation in the question.